# Joomla 4 Pre-Update Check Database Fail

Tags: joomla-4.x, database, upgrade

I installed Joomla on my webhost (Siteground) using the one-click installer package. I'm currently on v4.3.2

Everything appears to be working as expected apart from the Joomla update option. It keeps failing at the database check https://imgur.com/a/kpKTxKt

I've been reading this post and others have encountered the same issue https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/35915

Seems to be related to the web host installer.

In system > maintenance database I see *All database table structures are up to date.* Tried clicking Update Structure a few times but no change.

I'll get in touch with the web host and let them know, but wondering how I can fix this for now so that I'm able to upgrade to the latest version of Joomla.

Comment: Yes, I encountered something similar after an upgrade to v4. I was able to go into System Maintenance Database and then after a few clicks of Update Structure it suddenly all came ok. (At least, that's as far as I remember). Can you do anything within System Maintenance Database?

Comment: If you're still getting that error it might be worth getting onto the joomla community portal on mattermost: https://joomlacommunity.cloud.mattermost.com/login. You can ask a question like that on the live chat there, and you'd have direct access to more joomla core developers than on stack exchange or the joomla forum.